# flash light wont turn on / camera error

Tags: android, flashlight

hi i was looking around flashlight app source code and i modified a little bit coz when i minimise app the flashlight would turn off so i only used onDestroy() method to close the app state but when i turn off and on sometimes app doesnt even work it shows flash on but doesnot turn on flash light
here's what i did

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final ImageButton imgbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);





    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);



    getCamera();

    //button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isFlashOn) {
                turnOffFlash();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash OFF!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imgbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_off);

            } else {
                turnOnFlash();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash ON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imgbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void getCamera() {

    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        }catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}

private void turnOnFlash() {

    if(!isFlashOn) {
        if(camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
    }

}

private void turnOffFlash() {

    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;
    }
}

protected void onDestroy(){

    if(camera!=null){

        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }


} }
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to override:

1. `onStop()`

   ```
   @Override
     protected void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         if (camera != null) {
             camera.release();
             camera = null;
         }
     }
   ```
2. `onResume()`

   ```
   @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         if(hasFlash)
             turnOnFlash();
     }
   ```

to get the `hasFlash` I recommend to you to put this in `onCreate()` to know if device has flash or not available

```
hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

3. `onPause()`

   ```
   @Override
     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         turnOffFlash();
     }
   ```

*btw, you have code repeated...*

Comment: the app will turns off the light when i minimise the app i need to make it ON even its minimise and when i close the app ( it calls destroy() method ) then system  says" unfortunitely flashlight app has stopped "

Comment: then in onPause remove the turnOffFlash() method... put the logcat error in your question to see what's crashing

Comment: i removed turnOffFlash() from onPause() but that didnot worked, then i removded the method inside onStop() then it worked..now the prblm is app has stopped msg appears upon app is closed completely

Comment: thanks i figured out my issue.. i didnt call super.onDestory() inside onDestory() method that caused prbolem now its not showing any error

Comment: @JasbinKarki Yes of course you hace to call super.onDestroy()

Answer (score 0):

Use `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods and do your code here.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

       //Your code
    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

//Your code
    }
```

Comment: thankyou for your feedbacks..my apps gets crashed when i close the app is there a way to fix that i evn used turnOffFlash() upon destroy cant figure out this

Comment: Share your error and mark this ans as approved if helped.

Comment: system says unfornitutely app is closed here's log for it
https://pastebin.com/aEm5deSi

Comment: thankyou i figured out my issue and upvoted as well for ur help coz im new to stackoverflow its now showing upvotes publicly